# Effect of commuting observables on the probability of measuring a certain value

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, probability, commutator, observables

Say you can measure $3$ observables $(A, B, C)$ and you do the measurements in two different ways.
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1|}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\langle#1|#2\rangle}$

In the first setup, you first measure $A$ and block all except one of the outputs, say eigenstate $\ket{a^1}$. Then you measure $B$. Finally you measure $C$ and again block all except one eigenstate $\ket{c^1}$.

In this setup the probability of measuring $\ket{c^1}$ given $\ket{a^1}$ is:
$$
P_B(c^1 | a^1)=\sum_{i}|\braket{c^1}{b^i}|^2\cdot|\braket{b^i}{a^1}|^2=\sum_{i}\braket{b^i}{c^1}\braket{c^1}{b^i}\braket{a^1}{b^i}\braket{b^i}{a^1}
$$

In the second setup keep everything the same, but remove apparatus $B$.

The probability of measuring $\ket{c^1}$ given $\ket{a^1}$ is now:
$$
P_\bar{B}(c^1 | a^1)=|\braket{c^1}{a^1}|^2=\sum_{j}\sum_{i}\braket{b^j}{c^1}\braket{c^1}{b^i}\braket{a^1}{b^j}\braket{b^i}{a^1}
$$
Where the expression was expanded by applying the completeness relation $\sum_{i}\ket{b^i}\bra{b^i}=\textbf{1}$ twice.

The question is how to prove that either $[A, B]=0$ or $[B, C]=0$, in the absence of degeneracy, is a sufficient condition so that $P_B=P_\bar{B}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is how to prove that either $[A, B]=0$ or $[B, C]=0$, in the absence of degeneracy, is a sufficient condition so that $P_B=P_\bar{B}$. $
> \newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}
> \newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1|}
> \newcommand{\braket}[2]{\langle#1|#2\rangle}
> $

If $[A,B]=0$, then there exists a common eigenbasis between $A$ and $B$, and you can assume that you're working on that common eigenbasis for both the $\ket{a^i}$ and the $\ket{b^i}$. Thus, in your expression for $P_B(c^1 | a^1)$,
$$
P_B(c^1 | a^1)=\sum_{i}\braket{b^i}{c^1}\braket{c^1}{b^i}\braket{a^1}{b^i}\braket{b^i}{a^1}
,
$$
there will be one $i=i_0$ such that $\ket{b^{i_0}} = \ket{a^1}$ and thus $\braket{b^i}{a^1}=\delta_{ii_0}$.

The rest follows transparently.